# Reiten + sein oder haben

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Was bedeuten diese zwei Sätze:

1. Sie **ist** seit 5 Jahren geritten oder
2. Sie **hat** seit 5 Jahren geritten?

Für mich sagt der zweite Satz, dass die Frau seit 5 Jahren die Fähigkeit Reiten besitzt und der erste Satz impliziert, dass sie sich seit 5 Jahren ständig auf dem Pferd befindet.

Die Papierversion von Duden gibt ein Beispiel: Er hat seit frühersten Jugend geritten (den Reitsport betrieben).

Comment: Beide Sätze klingen in meinen Ohren nicht richtig, wenn du ihnen die Bedeutung mit der Fähigkeit gibst. Ansonsten kann man sowohl *haben* als auch *sein* verwenden, wobei es Unterschiede gibt: "Sie ist zum Bauernhof geritten." OK, aber nicht ("hat zum B. geritten")

Comment: Wie sollte dann deiner Meinung nach der korrekte Satz mit reiten klingen, der die Fähigkeit ausdrücken würde?

Comment: @Marcia "Sie *kann* seit 5 Jahren reiten".

Comment: Das steht aber im Widerspruch zu Duden

Comment: Ich meinte, wenn du sagst: "Beide Sätze klingen in meinen Ohren nicht richtig, wenn du ihnen die Bedeutung mit der Fähigkeit gibst", dann steht das im Widerspruch dazu, was Duden zum Thema sagt (siehe die letzten zwei Zeilen meiner Frage)

Comment: The example you give, does not imply that it is about the riding skill. It says, that he has been riding since he was young. You can also say "Er kann seit frühester Jugend reiten"

Comment: @Marcia So wie in der Antwort von Clemens "Sie reitet seit fünf Jahren." - Perfekt ist hier komisch, weil die Handlung/das Ereignis/der Zustand noch nicht beendet ist. Normalerweise verwendet man in einem Satz mit "seit"  das Präsens. siehe: https://learngerman.dw.com/de/präpositionen-vor-seit/l-40553076/gr-40553729

Comment: @Marcia Hab mir noch mal aufmerksam deine Frage durchgelesen. Du hast natürlich recht mit deinen Feststellungen oben. Trotzdem ganz koscher ist das "hat" meines Erachtens nicht. Gute Frage btw. :)

Answer (score 5):

The generic activity of sitting on a horse and moving can be expressed in most cases with both "sein" and "haben" (with some preference on "sein") as auxilary.

> Ich habe im Urlaub ein Pferd geritten
>
> Ich bin im Urlaub ein Pferd geritten

are both expressing the same thing. Both your example sentences thus mean the same thing to me, as they express this generic activity. I would, however, choose "sein" over "haben" in these examples - It's just more common.

The only case that I can come up with were "haben" does not work at all is *reiten* in the sense of *moving yourself from one place to another* like in splattne's example, when no object is present:

> Letztes Jahr bin ich von Rügen nach Usedom geritten

There are a number of meanings of *reiten*, though, that specifically ask for "haben":

- *Owning*, *occupying* or simply *having* a horse or other animal:

  > Beduinen haben früher Kamele geritten, heute nehmen sie Geländewagen
  >
  > Ich habe früher einen schönen Schimmel geritten (meaning "I kind of owned it")
- *Moving* the animal to a certain place by riding

  > Ich habe das Pferd auf die Weide geritten
- *Causing a specific condition of the horse* by riding

  > Ich habe das Pferd müde geritten
- *Causing a specific condition on yourself* by riding

  > Ich habe mir den Hintern wund geritten
- (Passive) in a figurative sense as "you must have been occupied by something"

  > Was hat dich denn geritten, als du dir dieses Auto gekauft hast?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me additionally if there is any difference in meaning between the two sentences I have put in my question?

Comment: See change in first paragraph - I don't see any difference in meaning, only in common usage.

Comment: I would choose "haben" over "sein" in the first two examples. Might be a regional difference. In any case, my feeling is that I use "sein" if there is no object and "haben" if there is one.

Comment: *haben* might imply a nuance of emphasis more on *directly having control over the horse* like in "ich bin Bus gefahren" vs. "ich habe den Bus gefahren" - Not sure if that's true for riding as well.

Comment: For completeness: also the sexual meaning of *reiten* would require *haben*. But this is, I think, because in the sexual meaning you would always add an accusative object (the other person involved, usually), and then sein is anyway not an option any more.

Answer (score 2):

Der erste Satz ist richtig, und deine Interpretation stimmt auch. Das liegt aber an der Kombination mit *seit 5 Jahren*. Wenn du sagen möchtest, dass sie seit 5 Jahren diesem Hobby frönt, solltest du

> Sie reitet seit 5 Jahren.

schreiben. Wenn hingegen sagen willst, dass sie beispielsweise eine bestimmte Strecke zurückgelegt hat, kannst du

> Sie ist zur Kneipe geritten.

verwenden.

Comment: Hat ist schon auch richtig, das muss man etwas differenzierter sehen:https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/reiten

Comment: Ich weiß, dass der Satz mit haben ist korrekt, will einfach die Bedeutung verstehen.

Comment: @Takkat: Stimmt, du hast recht. Besonders mit Objekt( _Ich habe einen Delfin geritten._) verwendet man eher_haben_, außer vielleicht in Süddeutschland.

Comment: "Sie reitet seit [Zeit]" kann genauso gut die andere, erste Bedeutung haben. Die Satzstellung an sich vermittelt nicht, dass es sich um ein Hobby handelt, sondern die Tatsache, dass 5 Jahre ein unrealistisch langer Zeitraum zum durchgängigen Reiten ist.

Comment: @Annatar: Das mit dem Hobby ist als Erläuterung zu meinem Beispielsatz gemeint. Ich habe nicht behauptet, dass _die Satzstellung vermittelt, dass es sich um ein Hobby handelt_.